# Is there a HTML5, jQuery Mobile or PhoneGap template similar to the iOS weather app?

Tags: html, templates, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm building a basic app for iOS and Android which has a look similar to the stock iOS Weather app. There will be multiple pages (for eg. 7, one for each day of the week) and the user will be able to swipe left or right between them, with a dotted indicator line at the bottom. Since this is pretty common functionality, I was wondering if there's already an existing template for this kind of an app, so I don't end up reinventing the wheel.

I tried out jqTouch and jQuery Mobile demos, but i didn't exactly find this. I found lots of swipe gestures, but neither of them had the dots at the bottom. The dots are key to my app and I don't want to create my own dots. If there's an example I may have missed, I'd appreciate a link to that!

[image: Mock UI of my app]
[image: Stock iOS Weather app]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!

Sencha Touch has a [Carousel](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/examples/production/kitchensink/#demo/carousel) effect that does exactly what I'm looking for.

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5330825/sencha-touch-html5-swipe-event-effect-from-left-to-right).